# querying values from several tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables containing id and names from different fields, and a master table that contains only ids, i need to create a query that return the names.

This is the structure (simplified)

table region = columns id, name

table country = columns id, name

table ethnics =  columns id, name

table religion = columns id, name

table master = columns region, country,ethnics, religion

table master contains ONLY ids for each column, and i need to return the names that matches those ids, but i can't create the proper JOIN syntax.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select region.name, country.name, ethnics.name, religion.name
from master
join region on (region.id = master.region)
join country on (country.id = master.country)
join ethnics on (ethnics.id = master.ethnics)
join religion on (religion.id = master.religion)
```

Then you can add any *where* clauses that you might need to filter the results.

Comment: Got it, it was using LEFT JOIN instead of a simple JOIN, thank you !